# Windows-7 Pro Remote Desktop stopped going full screen

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Was working perfect; remote desktop of laptop filled entire screen of workstation's 2nd monitor.
But now it's just a scrolling window that fills only 2/3.

Workstation: 2013 DELL OPTIPLEX 9010 Windows-7 Pro with (2) Samsung SyncMaster SA850T 27" monitors: #1 at 2560 x 1440 vertical, and #2 at 1440 x 2560 horizontal (the one for the remote desktop session to laptop)

Laptop: 2013 DELL Precision M4800 with Win-7 Pro.

I've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I solved it while writing this question...

SOLUTION:
Edit .rdp REMOTE DESKTOP config file at workstation with changes:

> Display tab:  Large, uncheck "Use all..", Colors Highest
>   Experience tab:  LAN
>   General tab:   SAVE
>   Hit Connect button

2nd monitor now shows remote desktop session at 2560 x 1440.  Ha cha!!

NOTE: Laptop local resolution was 1600 x 900.